# How to use Entity Framework as generic DataSource for DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, generic-programming

I'm trying to make `DataGridView` form which takes **generic** `DataSource` and displays data.

I can't get data bindings to work:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389592.

I tried passing `DataTable`, `DataSet` and `List` - but no luck... my problem is I want to use repository pattern and make a generic repository class which can work with different tables in my database.

This is my first attempt at writing the repository pattern code, and working with generic types.

```
public DataGridForm(IEnumerable<???> source) // TEntity or T can't be recognized by VisualStudio as a type!
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // TODO: Complete member initialization

    this.bindingSource.DataSource = source;
}
```

I'm having hard time with making this simple. Please any guidelines on how to achieve this?

I call this method:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

I know this is a loaded question but I need help in one way or another

~ ChenChi

**UPDATE:** the accepted answer works without a problem, real problem was that my AutoGenerateColumns property was by default set to *false*!

```
dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Setting it to true via code-behind made everything work... I was looking for this property in property windows and I couldn't find it?! Maybe some kind of Visual Studio bug I don't know...

Comment: This isn't a loaded question.  A "loaded question" is a question that contains a controversial or unjustified assumption.  That isn't the case here.

Comment: Wow still no help... :C

Comment: @Amy you're right, I meant to say run-on question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataSource` property of `BindingSource` accepts `object`. So it's enough to pass data as `object` to the constructor of your form:

```
public DataGridForm(object source) 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // TODO: Complete member initialization

    this.bindingSource.DataSource = source;
}
```

For run-time data-binding you don't need the type. But for any reason if you want to pass `IEnumerable<T>` to the form, the form should be `DataGridForm<T>` which has its side effects in designer.

Comment: I can't programatically change DataSource of DataGridVew, no matter what different BindingSource I set the columns of source I picked in Tasks always stay! Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see a relation between the Task panel and this question based on question descriptions. But the things that I can share is to clarify that what you need instead of *IEnumerable<???>*.  You don't need to work with `IEnumerable<T>` just for data-binding. I have many forms which use a `DataGridView` which is bound to a `BindingSource`. You want to set any kind of data as `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` and fortunately `BindingSource` has beed designed for such purpose. It's enough to box your data in object variables.

Comment: As a simple test, from toolbox, drop a `DataGridView` and a `BindingSource` on the `Form`. Then set `BindingSourc` as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`. Now if you want to be able to pass any kind of data to the Form, it's enough to change the constructor to what I used in the answer. Now if you create an instance of the form and pass data to it. it will show data, regardless of data type of the data. FOr example you can use `var db = new MyDbContext(); var data = db.Products.ToList(); var f = new DataGridForm(data); f.ShowDialog();`

Comment: It seems like datagridview did load the rows (in BindingNavigator) but no columns are displayed: http://prntscr.com/e6gvqt

Comment: Probably it's because you forget to bind `DataGridView` to `BindingSource`.

Comment: To test if the data can be shown in `DataGridView` or not, you even can bind it directly to `DataSource` of `DataGridView`.

Comment: I tried directly binding it and still no columns or rows shown... and I did set DataSource of DGV to BindingSource in the properties

Comment: So it means the `List` you are trying to show in `DataGridView` doesn't have displayable columns. I'm pretty sure if you use a [simple test (like this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070791/how-to-use-entity-framework-as-generic-datasource-for-datagridview/42117458?noredirect=1#comment71434937_42117458) you will get the correct result. But at the moment since I have not other information about your test environment, I have nothing more to share. Please to make the question more useful, post a completely simple test like I showed in above comment and talk about the result :)

Comment: I can't believe how stupid my problem was: I set dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true; and b00m everything is displayed the way it's supposed to! I tried looking for this property in Property window and it just isn't there xD then I set it in codebehind and it turns out it was set to false by default! At least I learned a few new things thank you and your answer is accepted as correct